# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time for the site's first new cycle of Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- at-the-office story blogs
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3023).

Comment: Wow. Not a second to spare. It's not even 2015 in the Eastern time zone in the US!

Comment: Would an office collaboration tool (free open source) be acceptable here? I was thinking of adding http://NemakiWare.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2016](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3470/community-promotion-ads-2016)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has become out-dated

Answer (score 13):

[image: Visit Startups.SE!]

Comment: This is a repost of the ad [posted late in 2014](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2966/325).

Comment: Thanks for reposting the AD!

Comment: @blunders can somebody from your community rework this ad for the new size requirements (300 x 250) and post to [this year's ads question](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/3470/325), assuming you're still interested in the publicity?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Workplace expertise wanted: how do you deal with a know-it-all?]

Comment: I hate this ad, why is it there?

Comment: @JonH it's here because it was proposed and enough people upvoted it to get it into the rotation.  If people downvote it it might fall out.  (And all ads reset each calendar year anyway.)  Some sites have had success with ads for specific questions to promote their communities, and that's what Community Building is trying here.

Comment: The post is more than a year old...I guess I don't get what this stuff is for??  I've read the post more than a gillion times thinking its something new but sure enough its the same thing.  Why do we even do such a thing?

Comment: This ad is a joke. A bad joke, at that. What's the link between Community Building and Perfect coworkers?

Comment: @DeerHunter there's no call to be rude.  The ad was an experiment; "joke" implies negative intent.  As for the connection, did you try clicking it?  The whole point of this style of community-promotion ad (which I've seen from other sites) is that some *individual questions or categories of questions* are relevant to multiple communities.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - sorry, no offense intended. I'm still baffled; this kind of cross-pollination is way above my head. It is a pity that the ad uses Arial, of all typefaces, and the lower textbox is jarringly mis-aligned.

Comment: @DeerHunter thanks.  Both workplaces and communities sometimes attract people who are, shall we say, *problematic*, so it seemed to the CB folks that Workplace folks might be able to help out with, or just be interested in reading, some questions there.  As I said, it was an experiment.  I'm not planning to propose this ad for next year; I think this style of ad works best with shorter runs anyway.  (So I might propose a *different* ad for CB, if any of the folks in that community can make a reasonable one (I am not a designer :-) ), but it won't be *this* one.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio - ah, okay, thanks. That was the first time I noticed the ad, clicked "comment", and landed here. I like the typeface in the "First job?" ad, though.

Answer (score 6):

[image: First job? We can help!]

Comment: This is a repost of last year's ad, but I think it'd be nice to spruce it up some, maybe tweak the graphics so it doesn't fade into the background quite so much.  Also, this is a good time to review the linked post.

Comment: It should be better posted to other SE the here.

Comment: @AnkitSharma good point.  Any thoughts on which ones?  (Graduated sites only; betas don't get community ads.)

Comment: i think programming site will work better.

Comment: @AnkitSharma that makes sense.  To make that happen, somebody who's active on Programmers would need to post this ad on their community-ads post (their analogue of this question).  If anybody does that, please leave a comment here with the link.

Comment: done on [DBA](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/community-promotion-ads-2015/1258#1258), [programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7070/community-promotion-ads-2015/7383#7383) and [superuser](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/9012/community-promotion-ads-2015/9370#9370). Its a different factor that i am active in none of them ;). Now you need to get support on this. I think it can done on many other se sites too. Can't think now.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Ad for Writers site]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 2):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]