# Some kind of bizarre font overlap issue

Tags: bug, design

Consider this answer: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/42592/

Sometimes, I see the following, which looks fine:

> [image]

But if I refresh the page enough, I find that about 1/5 of the time, it looks like this:

> [image]

It's not *just* that answer; some of the other answers get borked in a similar way:

> [image]

The fact that it's intermittent suggests that this is probably something to do with hot network questions (it's probably not the sidebar ads; I've seen the issue both happen and not happen when [this ad](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3026/10298) is shown).

This is happening on Chrome 43.0.2327.5 dev-m on Windows 8. I recognize that this isn't a supported browser, but I thought it might be worth noting in case this happens in Chrome stable too.

---

Lo and behold, it happens to me on meta, too! From this very post:

> [image]

Comment: I have never seen this - that's really strange...